# How to change the text "place your order" to "Book" present in checkout page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

My website is www.osdoc.in .
My website is built on wordpress and WooCommerce.
How can I change the text "Place Order" present in checkout page to "Book" ?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code by adding in `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', 'woo_custom_order_button_text' ); 

function woo_custom_order_button_text() {
    return __( 'book', 'woocommerce' ); 
}
```